# Extracting the name from a line

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

```
A   B   5   C   Hello: XYZ 'Main Search String', Searching In: '[Name] = "I just want this" AND [State] = Active ('NAME', 'ACT')
```

How to extract this string: `I just want this`

```
grep "Main Search String" filename | awk -F"tab" '{print $6}' | ??
```

Comment: You just want *what?*

Comment: So that input file is just one big line?

Comment: Please show us more lines so we can see a pattern (if there is any).

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\" '/Main Search String/ {print $2}' file
I just want this
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution (although it could use some more explanation). "Find lines with the `Main Search String` (which could be a regular expression); split the line on double quotes; print the thing between the first and second double quote". Only improvement would be to search for quotes _after_ `[Name]` - in case there is another expression before `[Name]` in the string. But no such information can be gathered from the question.

Comment: I could add some more information, but this is just simple function of `awk`, and now you have added some info, thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

using grep

```
grep -Po "\[Name\] = \"\K[^\"]*" file
grep -Po "(?<=\[Name\] = \")[^\"]*" file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/.*\[Name\] = "\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' YourFile
```

assuming the content is betwween `"` and for the tag [Name] on any line of your input file

Answer (score 0):

If you want more fun :)

```
$ cat /tmp/delme 
A   B   5   C   Hello: XYZ 'Main Search String', Searching In: '[Name] = "I just want this" AND [State] = Active ('NAME', 'ACT')

$ cat /tmp/delme | perl -e 'while (<>)  { if ( /.*[Name] = \"(.*)\"/ ) { print "$1\n"; } };'
I just want this
```

With this you can use the whole regex and pattern match things provided by perl...and perl is on almost every system as I know.Give it a try! ;)

EDITED for pattern found case:

```
$ cat /tmp/delme | perl -e 'while (<>)  { print "TEXT: ";print; if ( /.*Main Search String.*\[Name] = "(.*)\"/ ) { print "RESULT: $1\n"; } };'
TEXT: A   B   5   C   Hello: XYZ 'Main Search String', Searching In: '[Name] = "I just want this" AND [State] = Active ('NAME', 'ACT')
RESULT: I just want this
TEXT: A   B   5   C   Hello: XYZ 'Not Search String', Searching In: '[Name] = "I just want this" AND [State] = Active ('NAME', 'ACT')
```

Comment: You did forget that `Main Search String` is the search pattern to find the correct line.  Then from this line extract `I just want this`

Comment: in this case I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it in 13 characters plus the file name:

```
cut -d\" -f 2 text.txt
```

This command cuts the text into columns separated by the double-quotes. (-d\") That creates three columns. It prints out the second column with your answer (-f 2).

Like Lutz Horn said, you need to provide a bigger data set to test any of these commands. Many of them will fail if they do not represent the complete pattern they need to parse.